# Aliases for 'sudo /etc/init.d/'

Tags: alias, init-script

Are there any standards for aliasing `sudo /etc/init.d/`? I'm sure many people have considered cutting down these 17 characters to just 2 or so.

Comment: Interesting idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux with SysVinit (the traditional [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) implementation), the `service` command is a shell script that calls a script in `/etc/init.d`.

```
sudo service wibble restart
```

`service` also knows to look for [Upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) jobs if available. Upstart also comes with `start`, `stop`, `reload` and `restart` commands.

```
sudo restart wibble
```

I recommend keeping `sudo` to remind you that this is something performed as root.

Answer (score 7):

Something to consider, most systems have the "service" command, that could replace the /etc/init.d/ portion of your sudo command.

You could do for example:

`alias sserv="sudo service"`

example: (pay no attention to the root behind the curtain)

```
[root@talara javaWs.git]# sserv pdns restart
Restarting PowerDNS authoritative nameserver: stopping and waiting..done
Starting PowerDNS authoritative nameserver: started
```

Comment: Good to know. Never used that alias before.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [this snippet](https://github.com/grml/grml-etc-core/blob/master/etc/zsh/zshrc#L1917) in Grmls zshrc. It defines 5 function `Start` `Stop` `Restart` `Reload` `Force-Reload` to start/stop a daemon.